# Draw a Regular Side of Polygon

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics

I am having a `n` sided  regular polygon with length of each side is given `a1,a2...an`. 
How should i draw  this regular side polygon ?

The length of polygon are given in such a way it's is always possible to construct a  polygon from it.

If the radius `r` is given then i follow this ? 
But How should i draw with sides ?

```
x[n] = r * cos(2*pi*n/N)
y[n] = r * sin(2*pi*n/N)
```

Comment: Are all the sides the same length? If yes, what are `a1`, `a2`, ..., `an`? If no, then your polygon is not regular. Either way, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: No they are not of same length , i guess we can make all angle equals even if they are not of same length

Comment: No, you can't necessarily make all angles equal. (Think about the cases n=3 and n=4, for example; in the case n=3, for all angles to be equal you need all sides equal, and in the case n=4, opposite sides must have equal length.) You should reword your question: apparently you're *not* talking about regular polygons (which require equal angles *and* equal lengths). And if the polygon is perfectly general, then just the side lengths don't pin it down up to congruence, so it's not clear *which* of the infinitely many possible polygons you want to draw.

Comment: @MarkDickinson i have update it

Comment: Thanks. But it's still unclear *which* polygon you want. There are infinitely many quadrilaterals with side-lengths 3, 5, 3, 5, for example. So your question about how to draw "this polygon" doesn't make any sense. *which* polygon do you want to draw? The side lengths don't give enough information. Do you want all angles to be equal? If so, please state that in the question.

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of the input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Finding the vertex positions (i.e. a set of positions that satisfies the side lengths) of the polygon is equal to solving the following system of equations:

```
(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1^2) = a1^2
(x3 - x2)^2 + (y3 - y2^2) = a2^2
...
(x1 - xn)^2 + (y1 - yn^2) = an^2
```

There are a few ways to solve this. The easiest is probably to use some optimization library.

All methods require an initial guess of the vertex positions. A good guess may be a regular polygon with side length equal to the average side lengths. The radius of this polygon will be `1/2 * a / sin(pi / n)`, where `a` is the average side length and `n` is the number of vertices. Calculate the initial positions `x1, y1, x2, y2, ... xn, yn`. Then apply any solving technique. I present two of them in the following:

### Least-Squares

We transform the equations above to an error (energy):

```
E1 = ((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1^2) - a1^2)^2
...
```

The task then is to find the parameters, such that the sum of energies is smallest (least squares). There are a variety of solvers for these kinds of problems. Most methods focus on a special flavor. In this case, it is a non-convex, non-linear least-squares. But it does not look too bad. Hence, Levenberg-Marquardt should give pretty good and fast results. Of course, you can also try other methods.

Using libraries to solve this is usually very simple. Most libraries only require you to specify the energy function (just plug in the equation above) and an initial guess. Having specified this, they will directly give you the vertex positions. If you use C++, I can recommend [levmar](http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/index.html). But there should be libraries for most other languages as well.

A very easy method if you do not want to use libraries is parameter-wise optimization. The idea is to change a single parameter until the energy does not decrease any more (i.e. looking for a local minimum). Since a single parameter is only present in two equations, this can be done very efficiently. Do this for all parameters and for a couple iterations. The result will be a local minimum. Since this problem does not look too bad, I feel that the regular polygon-based initial guess will give you the global minimum.